# What are politicians working towards?

Tags: political-system, geopolitics, history

This may be a ridiculously stupid question, but I am curious as to whether there is a consensus on what a politician is supposed to do or is working towards. By this, I'm not looking for a partisan view, but really a more broad, concrete "end goal" that political figures are supposed to work towards.

This may broaden the question even further (maybe too much so), but is there a consensus about the politicians of the world as to what this goal is, or is it different depending on where it is?

Comment: The question is asked as if politicians were a different, tightly coordinated different kind of people. Reality is that most of them are just ordinary people trying to convince other people to support their opinions; the realities of political and economical systems make them do similar things (kiss babies, do campaigning, blame the opposition) but they support different outcomes and even value systems to other politics.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **The well-being of the public**.  For wide-ranging interpretations of *well-being*, and possibly of *public*.

The short answer is imprecise, but it's about as close as we can get.  [Philosophers have tried to tackle this question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_philosophy) as far back in history as democracies have been founded.  To answer with more context, we need to establish a common parlance on what we consider a politician, and make some assumptions on what we could defend to be their intended purpose.

> "A politician (from Classical Greek πόλις, "polis") is a person active in party politics, or a person holding or seeking office in government. In democratic countries, politicians seek positions within a government through elections or appointment." — [Wikipedia: Politician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politician)
>
> "Politics (from Greek: πολιτικός politikos, definition "of, for, or relating to citizens") is the making of a common decision for a group of people, that is, a uniform decision applying in the same way to all members of the group. It also involves the use of power by one person to affect the behavior of another person. More narrowly, it refers to achieving and exercising positions of governance — organized control over a human community, particularly a state. Furthermore, politics is the study or practice of the distribution of power and resources within a given community (a usually hierarchically organized population) as well as the interrelationship(s) between communities." — [Wikipedia: Politics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics)

So, **a politician is someone who holds or seeks to hold a position of governance, and one who influences public policy**.  Note that this does not imply or require a democracy; royalty, dictators, and warlords are also politicians in this sense.  **This is as far as we get in commonalities between politicians and a joint purpose.**

If we go from the charitable assumption that the well-being of the public is the end goal of politics, that still doesn't get us much further than just that assumption.  After all, depending on **your value system, your morality and ethics**, any of the following is defensible:

- The view that public well-being is best served through a single, overarching faith or belief system, fostering a sense of community and limiting internal conflict.
- The view that public well-being is best served through freedom of faith, promoting individual freedom and diversity.

Without arguing about viability or desirability of these views, they are *defensible* and *largely incompatible*.

Personally, I stick with my short answer up top: that **politicians *should* pursue the well-being of the public** as a kind of "greater good," and I believe this may be about as close to a consensus view as we are likely to find, and as far as we can venture without wading into specific policies.